# reading variable from console window in c

Tags: c, variables

```
void readStateTransitions(state *s){

    char kok[20];
    char y;

    int j=0;

    do{
        char alpha=' ';
        printf("Enter the alphabet\t ");
        scanf("%c", &alpha );

        //s->TrasitionsArray[j]->label=alpha;

    s->TrasitionsArray[j] = (struct trans*)malloc(sizeof(struct trans));   
    s->TrasitionsArray[j]->from = (struct state *)malloc(sizeof(struct state));
    s->TrasitionsArray[j]->to = (struct state *)malloc(sizeof(struct state));
    printf("For %s",s->label);
    //printf("Enter the next state for %s under %c",StatesArray[i].label,alphabet[j]);

    printf("Enter the next state under %c",alpha);
    scanf("%s",kok);
    for(int k=0;k<StatesNumber;k++){
        if(strcmp(StatesArray[k].label,kok)==0){
            s->TrasitionsArray[j]->to=&StatesArray[k];
        }
    }
    s->TrasitionsArray[j]->from=s;
    s->TrasitionsArray[j]->label=alpha;
    j++;
        printf("\n\n more transitions..??(y/n)");
    }while(getch()=='y');

}
```

I have this code  and here am asking the user to enter two variables one for alpha(char) and the second for kok(string) but the problem was that the program is ignoring the variable alpha and move directly to variable kok

image link http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/194/capturejey.jpg/

Comment: Do you mean that it's not waiting for input on alpha, only on kok?

Comment: I compiled your scanf calls using VS2010 and it worked fine for me.  Your screen shot doesn't match the code, you posted, so I suspect you're corrupting memory somewhere and breaking scanf.

Answer (score 1):

You need to consume the final \n. Since you just want to read a single character for the alpha variable, try using something like this:

```
alpha = getchar();
while (getchar() != '\n');
//scanf("%c", &alpha); //Instead of this
```

Just tested it here inside your code, worked for me.